# Netlify: Page not found except index.html

Tags: html, css, sass, netlify, vite

I deployed site on Netlify, then it shows only index.html, when i clicking links which goes to other pages in  my website it shows "Page not found",
I used vite to run and build my project, and Tailwind for css

Comment: Inspect your site folder structure with the href link found on your page

Comment: @HARISUMAID I checked it's correct

Comment: you could try building locally and could check your build files whether it contains your links correctly or not

Answer (score 1):

If you're building an SPA, you might want all URLs to serve `index.html` before processing the route logic. This can be done using [Netlify's File-based configuration file](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/).

> **Avoid 404s**
> If your app uses history pushstate to get clean URLs, you must add a rewrite rule to serve the index.html file no matter what URL the browser requests.

[More info on Builds configuration](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/javascript-spas/#build-configuration-for-javascript-spas)

---

**netlify.toml**

```
[build]
  command = "vite build"
  publish = "dist"

[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

Comment: No, it's not a SPA, developed using just html.